# postgres jdbc driver failover questions

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jdbc-postgres

I have 2 DB instances, 1 master `node1` 1 read replica `node2`.

I have 2 apps. 1 for writing `app1` one for reading `app2`

Here is the connection string for `app1`
`jdbc:postgresql://node1,node2/db?targetServerType=primary`.

Here is the connection string for `app2`
`jdbc:postgresql://node1,node2/db?targetServerType=preferSecondary` .

When `node1` fails, and `node2` gets promoted to master, will jdbc driver in `app1` auto connect to the `node2` for writing? Will the jdbc driver in `app2` start checking if a read replica exist and switch traffic if so (when `node1` come up)?

Answer (score 1):

The client connected to the failed primary server will connect to the promoted standby when it tries to reconnect. (But you must write the application so that it tries to reconnect.)

The client connected to the standby will stay connected when the standby is promoted. It won't switch over to a new standby server, unless you do that deliberately in your application. To test if you are connected to a standby server, you can run

```
SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();
```

That will return `TRUE` on the standby.

Comment: Thanks, I assume this is the behavior of the postgres jdbc driver. In the case where app connects to the standby when standby is promoted to master. Is there a way to detect the promotion event and switch over to read only instance in jdbc driver?